# Polars idiomatic way of aggregating n consecutive rows of a data frame

Tags: python, aggregate, python-polars, rolling-computation

I'm new to Polars, and I ended up writing this code to compute some aggregating expression over segments of `n` rows:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 1, 3, 8, 62, 535, 4213]})

(
    df.with_columns(index=pl.int_range(pl.len(), dtype=pl.Int32))
    .group_by_dynamic(index_column="index", every="3i")
    .agg(pl.col("a").mean())
)
```

For the example I set `n==3` for `7` rows, but think of a smallish `n` of about `100`, for a multicolumn data frame of about `10**6` rows.

I was wondering if this is the idiomatic way of doing this type of operation.
Somehow `group_by_dynamic` over an `Int32` range seems overkill to me: I was wondering if there is a more direct way of doing the same aggregation.

Comment: you can use `with_row_index` instead of `with_columns` in your query

Comment: @RomanPekar nope: `with_row_index` returns an unsigned index, while `group_by_dynamic` insists on signed integers.

Comment: You can assign group numbers with modulo arithmetic e.g.  `.group_by((pl.int_range(pl.len()) % 3 == 0).cum_sum(), maintain_order=True)` but it's still somewhat clunky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO your solution using [`group_by_dynamic`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic.html#polars.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic) already follows best practices when it comes to the aggregation.

However, you can simplify the creation of the index column quite a bit
using [`pl.DataFrame.with_row_index`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_row_index.html). As the result is unsigned (and `group_by_dyanmic` only allows for a *signed* integer index column), you'll need to pass an expression doing the casting, i.e.

```py
(
    df
    .with_row_index()
    .group_by_dynamic(index_column=pl.col("index").cast(pl.Int32), every="3i")
    .agg(pl.col("a").mean())
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`group_by_dynamic`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic.html#polars.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic) allows one row to be a member of multiple groups, which is not really needed in your case.

What you need is to assign a "bucket" number to each row and then group by this number. This is similar to [`ntile()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-window.html) sql function.

To achieve that you can use, for example, `pl.int_range(pl.len()) // 3 = (0,0,0,1,1,1,2...)` as `group_by` column:

```py
(
    df
    .group_by(pl.int_range(pl.len()) // 3, maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col("a").mean())
)

┌─────────┬────────────┐
│ literal ┆ a          │
│ ---     ┆ ---        │
│ i64     ┆ f64        │
╞═════════╪════════════╡
│ 0       ┆ 1.666667   │
│ 1       ┆ 201.666667 │
│ 2       ┆ 4213.0     │
└─────────┴────────────┘
```